# declaration or statement expected javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Typescript 1.7 and React 0.14 with the new ES6 systax and I'm having the following destructuring assignment, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as well.

```
let x0, x1, y0, y1;
if(this.props.viewport) {
    {x0, x1, y0, y1} = this.props.viewport;
}
```

However, I'm getting the `Declaration or statement expected` error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure the destructuring assignment doc page mentions that... wrap the left hand side in paretheses.

Comment: then I get an `Invalid left-hand side of assignment expression` error

Comment: Did you do it exactly as told by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment ?

Comment: @JanDvorak apparently no :) found the answer. thanks!

Comment: IDE was showing this to me, even with an empty file. Closing and opening removed the warning

Answer (score 84, accepted):

So, I found the problem. Had to wrap the whole line in parenthesis. So the following is correct.

```
let x0, x1, y0, y1;
if(this.props.viewport) {
    ({x0, x1, y0, y1} = this.props.viewport);
}
```

Comment: Why the parenthesis are needed?

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS. this is the syntax for destructuring after declaration as shown in the example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Syntax

Comment: PSA: You may just need to restart Webstorm/VSCode

Comment: @CobieFisher genius idea, thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem because I was trying to use `case` as a variable name e.g. `var case = ...`. Now I know this error was because `case` is already used by JavaScript's [Switch Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Comment: This happened to me, too. oops!

Answer (score 0):

If you create the variables and assign to them the values in the same line, you can do it like so:

```js
let person = {name: "Alex", age: 23, favoriteColor: "orange"}

let {name, age} = person

document.write(name + " is " + age + " years old")
```

In case you first declare the variables and then on another line you assign the values, the approach is different, it needs the parenthesis to be parsed correctly. Like so:

```js
let person = {name: "Alex", age: 23, favoriteColor: "orange"}

let name, age;

({name, age} = person)

document.write(name + " is " + age + " years old")
```

In case you want to assign values to a property from an object or a getter inside a class, it is a little bit tricky, it would look like so:

```
({name: this.name, age: this.age} = this.person)
```